# Give 404 to desktop users using htaccess

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I'm looking for code that will detect if the user is on a desktop, then give them 404 error.

For example:
If a desktop user visit example.com/loreupsum then give them a 404 error, but bots and mobile users get the URL contain (the actual page).

I found this code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*(MSIE.*Windows\ NT|Lynx|Safari|Opera|Firefox|Konqueror) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(loreupsum)$ [L,R=404]
```

But this give the 404 error to all the users.

Comment: What are the browser(s) and user-agent strings of the browser(s) you don’t think should be blocked, but are? "I found below code" - Where did you _find that code_? At the very least it is incomplete? `Safari` and `Firefox` are certainly contained in the mobile UA string, as is `Opera` ("Opera Mini"). Having an additional condition to make an exception for the word `mobile` and `mini` (case-insensitive) would get you a bit closer.

Comment: I'd say that code you found has been written about 20 years ago, considering the strings mentioned in there. And for a very special ecosystem as well, considering the exotic browsers mentioned. Sure it is a good approach to solve a task by blindly copying such thing?

Comment: @arkascha Ya blindly copying isn't a good approach but i didn't find the latest code for what I'm trying to do that's why i did some edit to check whether it work or not.

Comment: Then maybe you should try another approach: instead of search somewhere, trying to guess what might make sense or work, which you obviously can't without knowlege ...why not simply start to learn how that tool actually works, so that you can implement your own solution and enhance it, step by step? The official documentation of the rewriting module is of excellent quality. And there are various really good tutorials easily to be found.

Comment: @arkascha yes you're right but it takes time that's why i came to ask professionals for the solution. However, I started finding own solution but not yet get the solution hope soon will get.

Comment: If you want to operate a service on the internet you need to understand the tools you are using. There is no way around that. The more you do yourself the more you learn, that always is the case. So do not hesitate, go!

Comment: your word helped to me scratch my mind and after knowing about that tool, i got the solution.

Comment: @MrWhite someone already posted the solution and i already accepted, a person just have to execute the below template using add_action on funtions.php of theme.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be acheive using wp_is_mobile() that looks at the $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] to determine whether we're in a mobile context.

Here is a basic page template example (give_404.php) which is on the theme diretory:

```
<?php

/**
 * Template Name: Mobile restricted page
 *
 * @since 1.0.0
 */
if ( ! wp_is_mobile() ) {

    global $wp_query;

    $wp_query->set_404();

    status_header( 404 );

    get_template_part( 404 );

    exit();

};

get_header();

//...

get_footer();
```

then trigger the above template using add-action for the specfic url you want to give 404 to desktop users from fucntions.php of the theme:

```
add_action('wp', function() {
if ( trim(parse_url(add_query_arg(array()), PHP_URL_PATH), '/') === 'pagename' ) {
include(locate_template('give_404.php'));
exit();
}});
```

But how one can do it for multiple URLs. Is it possible to made a file suppose block_url.txt? That has all the url for which above template triggers.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`wp_is_mobile()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_is_mobile/) which is looking at the `$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']` do determine whether we're in a mobile context.

Here is a basic page template exemple:

```php
<?php

/**
 * Template Name: Mobile restricted page
 *
 * @since 1.0.0
 */
if ( ! wp_is_mobile() ) {

    global $wp_query;

    $wp_query->set_404();

    status_header( 404 );

    get_template_part( 404 );

    exit();

};

get_header();

//...

get_footer();
```

> But why would you do such an horrible thing !

Comment: can you please let me how to implement above code and also how can i do for a specific url; above code seems to be for whole site?

Comment: That only means you are using a black box, which in turn means you understand even less whether it works, why and how.

Comment: @arkascha yes, you're that's why i asked for the implementation process.

Comment: @amarinediary the code you mentioned worked like a charm; i did using add_function and i achieved for what i'm looking.